# how do i remove redundant tuples in microarray data using java programming?

Tags: java, weka, redundancy

In WEKA-a data mining software for the MICROARRAY DATA, how can i remove the redundant tuples from the existing data set? The code to remove the redundancy should be in JAVA.

i.e, the data set contains data such as

```
H,A,X,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
D,R,O,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,0
H,A,X,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
C,S,O,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,0
H,A,X,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
```

here the tuples 1,4,5 are redundant.

The code should return the following REDUNDANCY REMOVED data set...

```
H,A,X,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
D,R,O,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,0
C,S,O,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the classes that implements the [Set](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) such as [java.util.HashSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html/).

You can load your data set into the Set and then extract them either by converting to an array via the Set.toArray() method or by iterating over the set.

`Set<Tuple> tupleSet = new HashSet<Tuple>();`

```
      
for (Tuple tuple: tupleList) {    
    tupleSet.add(tuple);    
}  

// now all of your tuples are unique  
for (Tuple tuple: tupleSet) {    
    System.out.println("tuple: " + tuple);  
}
```

Comment: in addition to your suggestion you must also implement the equals and hashCode methods of Tuple. otherwise the redundancy calculation will be based on the Tuple object reference only